# Create column in geopandas dataframe using assign method

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have the following piece of code which works perfectly:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
gdf["geometry"] = gdf.apply(lambda x: Point(x.longitud, x.latitud),axis=1)
```

I would like to create the column 'geometry' using the assign method but I don't know how. I have tried something like the following but it does not work.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})\
.assign(geometry, apply(lambda x: Point(x.longitud, x.latitud),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='epsg:4326').assign(geometry=lambda x: [Point(lon, lat) for lon, lat in zip(x.longitud.tolist(), x.latitud.tolist())])
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: @JavierMonsalve Stay tuned, I'm installing `geopandas` and trying to figure out why.

Comment: @JavierMonsalve The problem is `x.longitud` is Series, `Point` seems not taking Series object. I'm now looking ways to do that.

Comment: @JavierMonsalve How about `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,{'init': 'epsg:4326'}).assign(geometry=lambda x: [Point(lon, lat) for lon, lat in zip(x.longitud.tolist(), x.latitud.tolist())])`?